# retrieve patterns that exactly match all regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, match

I have a database of subgraphs that looks like this:

```
t # 3-231, 1
v 0 94
v 1 14
v 2 16
v 3 17
u 0 1 2
u 0 2 2
u 0 3 2
t # 3-232, 1
v 0 14
v 1 94
v 2 19
v 3 91
u 0 1 2
u 0 3 2
u 1 2 2
t # 3-233, 1
v 0 17
v 1 91
v 2 16
v 3 94
u 0 1 2
u 0 3 2
u 1 2 2
t # 3-234, 1
v 0 90
v 1 93
v 2 102
v 3 95
u 0 1 2
u 0 3 2
u 1 2 2
```

I would like to retrieve all transactions that contains the following patterns: 'u 0 1 2' and 'u 0 2 2' along with transaction id (ex. line starts with t #).

I used the following code to accomplish this job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $input = shift @ARGV or die $!; 

open (FILE, "$input") or die $!;

while (<FILE>) {

my @fields = ('t', 'u\ 0\ 1', 'u\ 0\ 2');  
my $field_regex = join( "|", @fields );
my @field_lines;

    push( @field_lines, $_ ) if ( /^(?:$field_regex) / );
    last if @field_lines == @fields;

push @field_lines, "";

print join( "\n", sort @field_lines );
}

close FILE;
```

However, it retrieves patterns, when only one line match, such as:

```
t # 3-231, 1
u 0 1 2
u 0 2 2
t # 3-232, 1
u 0 1 2
t # 3-233, 1
u 0 1 2
t # 3-233, 1
u 0 1 2
```

My ultimate goal is to retrieve transactions that completely match to my regex, such as

```
t # 3-231, 1
u 0 1 2
u 0 2 2
```

Thank you for your help!

Olha

Comment: Split the input into blocks beginning with `t` lines. Then check whether the block matches the `u` patterns.

Comment: `t # 3-436, 1` in your desired result doesn't appear in your sample data, does it? Where did it come from?

Comment: @Olha Kholod: The output you were showing doesn't match with any of your input files transction ids. Could you pls confirm what would be the desired output you're expecting?

Comment: I apologize about it. I have edited the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way: keep the current transaction-id on hand, and store lines of interest in an arrayref associated with that transaction-id key in a hash.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';    
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

my @fields = ('u 0 1', 'u 0 2');  
my $field_regex = join '|', map { quotemeta } @fields;
    
my (%trans, $tid);

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^t #/) { 
        $tid = $_; 
        next;
    }   
  
    push @{$trans{$tid}}, $_  if /$field_regex/;
}

dd %trans;

# foreach my $tid (sort keys %trans) { 
#     say $tid;
#     say for @{$trans{$tid}};
# }
```

I use `while (<>)` which reads line by line all files given on command line when the program is invoked (or `STDIN`), for simplicity here. I use `Data::Dump` to show a complex data structure; there is `Data::Dumper` in the core for that.

The [qotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) escapes all ASCI non-"word" characters, that can throw off regex, and this includes spaces.

The program above in general loses the order of transaction-id's from the file, since hash keys are unordered, while it keeps the order of lines for each id since those are on an array.  This is not hard to remedy if needed.

Tested only with the provided data file.

Comment: If `scalar @{$trans{$tid}}` becomes `2`, we may have to print the data I guess. that's what I could see in the question. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: switch to your solution, because it's applicable to wide range of patterns without hardcoding regex.

Comment: @OlhaKholod Thank you for the comment -- that is important: in general, don't hard code regex-minded additions in a list of strings to match.  Those should be literal strings that you want, and then that list (array) can be further manipulated as needed.   Sorry that I didn't get to comment on your own code, time was too short for that; will do that when there's time.

Comment: @vkk05  Perhaps, I wasn't sure of details so I left it generic, with all lines. I intend to review the OP code and comment for them, since they posted so nicely, and then I may be able to figure out that point

Answer (score 3):

This type of pattern is most easily handled by treating the file contents as blocks rather than lines.

Here is an easy example (with your data):

```
use strict;

my $big_string;
my $trans;
my $block;

open my $fh, '<', '/tmp/file.txt' or die "Can't open file $!";

$big_string = do { local $/; <$fh> };

while ($big_string=~/^(t\h*#\h*[0-9,\h-]+[\s\S]*?(?=(?:^t\h*#\h*[0-9,\h-]+)|\z))/mg) {
    $block=$1;
    $trans=$1 if $block=~/^(t\h*#\h*[0-9,\h-]+)/;
    if ($block=~/^(u\h+0\h+[12]\h+2)/m){
        print "$trans\n";
        for ($block=~/^(u\h+0\h+[12]\h+2)/mg) {
            print "$1\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
t # 3-231, 1
u 0 2 2
u 0 2 2
t # 3-232, 1
u 0 1 2
t # 3-233, 1
u 0 1 2
t # 3-234, 1
u 0 1 2
```

This assumes that your data fits easily into memory. If not, there are many ways to read a file block by block as well.

If you only want the blocks that have more than one match to the second regex:

```
while ($big_string=~/^(t\h*#\h*[0-9,\h-]+[\s\S]*?(?=(?:^t\h*#\h*[0-9,\h-]+)|\z))/mg) {
    $block=$1;
    $trans=$1 if $block=~/^(t\h*#\h*[0-9,\h-]+)/;
    @matches=$block=~/^(u\h+0\h+[12]\h+2)/mg;
    if (scalar @matches >1) {
        print "$trans\n";
        print join "\n", @matches;
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
t # 3-231, 1
u 0 1 2
u 0 2 2
```

And, of course, TIMTOWDI:

```
my @result = do{ local @_ = split(/^(t\h+#[\h\d,-]+)/m, $big_string); 
                        @_[1..$#_]};

for my $i (0 .. @result/2-1) {
    @matches=$result[2*$i+1]=~/^(u\h+0\h+[12]\h+2)/mg;
    if (scalar @matches>1){
        print "$result[2*$i]\n";
        print join("\n", @matches);
    }
}   
t # 3-231, 1
u 0 1 2
u 0 2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`perl -lne '@h=($_) if /^t #/; push @h,$_ if /^u 0 [12] 2/; if (@h==3) { print shift @h while @h }' file`

reset & hold the transaction line; append the matching lines; print and reset if you accumulate 3 lines.